# SQL Server. Hacer un group by de todos los campos de la tabla

Tags: group-by, tsql

estoy intentando reducir el número de filas de una tabla con 300 millones de filas.
Me cuesta cargar la tabla completa así que es difícil estudiar los campos.

He intentado hacer un GROUP BY de **todos los campos** sumando un campo de importe y he conseguido reducir de 300 millones a 200 mil filas aproximadamente, pero la consulta tarda al menos 8-10 minutos en completarse.

Mi pregunta es: ¿es realmente eficiente hacer un GROUP BY de todos los campos de una tabla? ¿Hay algún caso en el que se haya dado esta solución?

Gracias

Comment: la pegunta es: ¿que es lo que necesitas hacer con esta tabla?

Comment: Estoy realizando informes en power bi, pero el tamaño de la tabla es muy grande y me gustaría reducir el número de filas.

Comment: Realmente lo que necesito saber es si esa resolución sería válida, o si es muy raro un caso en el que se de una agrupación por todos los campos

Comment: Es un informe el que determina el tipo de consulta que tienes que hacer, el tamaño de la tabla es indiferente.